# Getting input in java

Tags: java, io

I wanna to get input from console while it has input.
Now my code is this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = "s";
while (word.length() > 0) {
    word = scan.nextLine();
    if (!word.equals(""))
        t.addWord(word);
}
```

but in some cases it gives me `no such element exception` . I don't know what is the case that cause the problem,because somebody else  checks my code.

also I checked `hasNext` in my while condition. 
it works wrong

```
String word;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    word = scan.nextLine();
    t.addWord(word);
}
```

what should I do? what is my problem?

Comment: `it works wrong` then what is right that you expected?

Comment: the code that @copeg said is what i excepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code snipped does not perform the same length check on `word` as does the first code snippet. Presuming you wish to terminate the while loop if `word` is just an empty line, then place a condition that will breaks out of the loop if this condition is met:

```
while ( scan.hasNextLine() ){
    word = scan.nextLine();
    if ( word.length() > 0 ){
        t.addWord(word);
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(sc.hasNext()){

//logic here

}
```

This is all you have to do.