# Getting input java

Tags: java, io

same as this[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266461/getting-input-in-java)  I want to get input from user while he/she give me strings. but the difference is that now before I get strings , I must get 26 numbers. so this code works wrong in getting `myStrings`. what should I do?

Wrong code:

```
for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
        alphabet[i] = scan.nextFloat();
    }
    String infix;
    int i = 0;
    String[] myStrings = new String[100];

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        infix = scan.nextLine();
        if (infix.length() > 0) {
            myStrings[i] = infix;
            i++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

**edit:**  wrong means , when I debug it, before I give strings as an input (after giving numbers) , this line :(" `while (scan.hasNextLine())` ") passes , and `infix` in this line( `infix = scan.nextLine();` is "") so the while , doesn't work correct. and break after that.

Comment: What do you mean wrong? why is it wrong?

Comment: The first comment of the linked question applies here as well: `this code works wrong` in what way? Please be more specific in your questions or people will tend to close them.

Comment: " I want to get input from user while he/she gives me strings." and this code doesn't do that @Stultuske

Comment: so those Strings aren't input? basically, there is nothing wrong with the code, you just have changed requirements and haven't adjusted the code yet?

Comment: i have edited my post . @Stultuske see it again please :)

Comment: the while works correct, maybe you should check your input file. seems there is an empty line there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that after reading a float from the scanner, a newline `"\n"` is left in the scanner, this means that when the first `scan.nextLine()` runs, it gets that leftover newline, which results in your code hitting the else block, and breaking out of the loop.

You can either get the next line before your loop:

```
String infix;
int i = 0;
String[] myStrings = new String[100];
infix = scan.nextLine(); //Get it here to throw away the new line

while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    infix = scan.nextLine(); //Should contain whatever the user entered
    //code
}
```

Or, when you get the float from the loop, you can use `Float.parseFloat()` combined with `scan.nextLine()`, like so:

```
for (int i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
    alphabet[i] = Float.parseFloat(scan.nextLine());
}
```

Which will stop there from being a new line left in the scanner after you receive the last float

Answer (score 0):

That's a common issue in Java. After getting the input from user using Scanner like nextInt();, nextDouble(); etc, you need to consume a line with a empty scan.nextLine();, because those methods doesn't consume the new line expression "\n". , before you can get some strings.